# Too many Trojans

Tags: windows-vista, virus

My computer is now basically a breeding ground for [Trojans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29). I can't open up Firefox or Opera without getting redirected to some training job site or have a fake Windows XP virus scan screen open up.

I'm typing this on Chrome, which seems fine. I can't install [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Security_Essentials) or enable [OneCare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_OneCare) and can't enable the [Security Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Action_Center).

I ran this: http://www.anti-virus-professional.com/

It found 5 bad files. I manually went to the locations where it detected them and deleted them.

The baddies are still on my computer, though. IS MY BATTLESHIP SUNK?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just installed a nice piece of **[rogue security software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_security_software)**.

Follow these instructions to remove the program manually:

**[How to Remove Anti-Virus Elite](http://www.anti-spyware-101.com/remove-antiviruselite)**

Then download and run **[MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)**, do a **Quick Scan** and remove all infections.

Note: it is essential that you disable/remove [Anti-Virus Elite](http://www.spywareremove.com/removeAntiVirusElite.html) first as it will prevent the installation of [MBAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwarebytes%27_Anti-Malware)!

Comment: Wow thanks, my father recommended the Anti-Virus Elite thingie, should've known better. :P, Scanning now with MBAM. Thank you so much.

Comment: your father did probably pay them and was delighted how the annoyances came to an end. that's they these rogue programs work.

Answer (score 2):

Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure ;). Alternately I'd suggest running an offline AV scan off a CD, or [UNetbootin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin). [Avira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avira) has a CD, and UNetbootin has a variety. Bypassing the AV means a better chance of detecting well hidden viruses. Once this is done, the usual [Malwarebytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwarebytes%27_Anti-Malware)/AV technique should be done, following which if anything is broken, running `sfc /scannow` or doing a repair install might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I've never even heard of that anti-virus program. I'd recommend [Avira](http://www.free-av.com/) as it is an excellent and trusted free AV solution. But if you're computer is riddled with as many trojans as you say it is, maybe a full reformat would be better for you. Reformatting is typically faster to have you up and running virus free, assuming you have the drivers and applications ready to reinstall. A scan can take a few minutes up to a few hours depending on how much your system has been bogged down. A fresh Windows installation usually takes less than an hour. Back up any files you want to keep before doing anything drastic.

Comment: "Reformatting is typically faster to have you up and running" ... maybe for us who have a nice variety of Ghost images to choose from. :)

Comment: Well thats even faster. But all you need is your windows disc and your drivers and necessary programs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have a large harddrive with a lot of media and numerous programs, reformatting is not practical at the moment. But I'm downloading Avira, at this point the more real AV the merrier, lol.

Comment: Remove antivirus elite first and foremost though.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I recommend is that you download: (1, 2 and 3 if you are an expert, 2 and 3 if you are an average user)

1. [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)
2. [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/)
3. [Spybot Search and Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html). (Also, from download page, get the latest definitions)

Now, keep all these files in a directory or on a USB stick.

Look at your hosts file - `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and make sure there are only one or two entries for localhost, or if there are more and you know why, leave it.

**(If using internet explorer) ** Next, go to internet options and in the last tab, click `Reset` under `Reset Internet Explorer Settings`. This should remove all toolbars and any "bad" settings.

Boot in to safe mode and install [Spybot Search And Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html), let it run and remove all the rubbish.

Next, install [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/).

Lastly, if you think you know what you are doing, use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and check Windows Startup and get rid of all the extra entries (if there are any... or just give your computer a spring clean).

Comment: you can disable it all you want with Autoruns, it does come back immediately, Microsoft Security Essentials will not even pick it up and Spybot S&D will suffer the same fate as MBAM, Anti-Virus Elite will prevent the installation (even in safe mode) ... unless you kill the processes, unregister the DLLs and and delete the registry key.

Comment: ... I have used Autoruns for years for this situation and even skipping out safe mode, it is better than many AV scanners... and I suggested the order above that Autoruns should be run last... I have done this order for many years without any problems.

Comment: well, not  the security essentials, used to be AVG or Nod32, but it still works!

Comment: yep, Autoruns is a killer, however, you'll have to kill more than just the one obvious entry, and without exactly knowing which files you're looking for it's a bit of a challenge. :)